# Изменить итоговую стоимость корзины

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Задача такая, при выборе метода оплаты наложенный платеж, на странице checkout, нужно добавить 10% от стоимости заказа к самому заказу. Например если оплата картой то стоимость обычная 10000 руб, при выборе наложенного платежа стоимость всей корзины (не отдельного товара) меняется на 11000 руб.
По возможности сделать это в ajax

Нашел такой код, добавляет 10% к стоимости корзины, но как тут сделать проверку на то что выбран нужный метод оплаты, а именно наложенный платеж?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','woocommerce_custom_surcharge'      );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
global $woocommerce;

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return;

$percentage = 0.10;
$surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;    
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Surcharge', $surcharge, true, '' );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На странице checkout работает такой код:

```
if( $available_gateways['cod']->chosen ) { ... }
```

Глобальная переменная `$available_gateways` содержит массив объектов, описывающих методы платежа. `cod` (cash on delivery) - наложенный платеж. `chosen` принимает значение `true`, когда данный метод выбран.